# I am trying to pass params in stack.screen but having an error

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I have the following Stack.Screen in my App.js and want to access it in another screen but don't know how to do it.

**App.js file:** using: { id: route.params } - When I console.log(id) it returns exactly the id. Now I would like to return the same id inside the following: `<Text>Edit Screen - {id}</Text>`

```
<Stack.Screen name='ShowScreen' 
          component={ShowScreen} 
          options={({route, navigation}) => ({ 
            title: 'Post Details', 
            headerRight: () => (              
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Edit', { id: route.params })}>
                <AntDesign name="edit" style={styles.iconStyle} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )   
        })} 
        />
```

**EditScreen.js file**

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const EditScreen = ({route}) => {
    const { id } = route.params
    console.log(id)

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Edit Screen - {}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    //
})

export default EditScreen
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution after two days of searching:
I just add the id after the params in the app.js as follow { id: route.params.id }

```
<Stack.Screen name='ShowScreen' 
          component={ShowScreen} 
          options={({route, navigation}) => ({ 
            title: 'Post Details', 
            headerRight: () => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Edit', { id: route.params.id })}>
                <AntDesign name="edit" style={styles.iconStyle} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )   
        })} 
        />
```